# how to remove auto appended query string when using sendredirect?

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

When I am using 
HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect(), I found there is always some query string appended to the forwarded page. How to remove those query string when redirecting?

Comment: Can you put an example of the URL you get?

Comment: Hm, I can't believe that and never saw that in reality. Which servlet engine do you use? Maybe your framework adds some information or you use URL rewriting for session management?

Answer (score 0):

When you saw you are redirecting, you are indeed redirecting to another resource which may or may not be in your webapp. This includes sending a response to the client with the redirecting URL in the header. The client must be capable of picking up the redirect URL and hit it.

Forward on the other hand is forwarding the same request to another resource in the same webapp. This does not involve a round trip.
So, In essence unless you pass any query parameter in the URL while redirecting, it will not have any query param. If you are not passing any query param, then you may have to probe whether the client adds any query param itself. You may also need to check you are not using `encodeRedirectURL`.